# при buildozer android debug deploy run ошибка

Tags: python, linux, kivy, buildozer

[image: error buildozer]

когда запускаю buildozer android debug deploy run (buildozer -v android debug) выдает ошибку.
Объясните как можно проще.
Запускал в виртуалке не смог сюда текст вписать.

Я пытался создать приложение с интеграции в android (java-python), запустил biuldozer (после установки, магии и шаманства) для того чтобы создать наконец рабочий пакет, но он не создался. Есть JDk, есть python3.7 , python2.

Comment: Здравствуйте, опишите лучше сам вопрос, опишите цель и другие вещи. А так, нету нормального поведения к вопросу - что пытались сделать, что сделали, цель, общий вопрос. И по этому, никто не поймёт вопрос и пройдёт мимо)

Comment: В ощибке написано, что у вас `main.py` файла нет. Возможно в этом проблема

Comment: я его добавил, а все равно не запускается, я уже другую os запустил, по-другому пытался установить , а все безполезно